# What Does $* mean in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix, rm

I am working on shell scripting, where I find the below code ,

```
rm -f  $*
```

What does this line exactly mean?

Comment: $* means all parameters starting from first given in command.

Comment: `man bash` will explain that and much more...